# JScolor style input text field

Tags: jscolor

I am using JColor to pick a color in a text field.
Before I used Jscolor I had a class='....' to style the input text field.
To use Jscolor I had to change this in class='color', but my original styling is gone now. 
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

An element can have multiple classes if you delimit them with spaces.
Let's say your `<input>` was originally of class `myClass`, and you want to make it of class `color` for use with jscolor. To do this, simply write `class = "myClass color"` when creating your `<input>` element.

Here is an example page I made that has an `<input>` with custom styling that is also configurable with jscolor:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<style>
/* custom css */
.myClass {
    width: 100%;
    cursor:wait;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- uses jscolor and the above CSS styling for "myClass" -->
<input class = "myClass color" value = "#FF0000">
</body>
</html>
```